# how can I abort specific ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

I have an Extjs store which perform ajax request to php script

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.store1', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'MyApp.model.model1',
autoSync: true,
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
url: 'script.php', // File to connect to
method: 'GET',                                           
reader: {
type: 'json',
 root: 'result'
},
}
})
```

The php returnes data from postgresql query which takes long time to run. I want to allow the user to stop loading the store when he press a stop button and I want the query to be deleted from the database.

I have tried this code:

```
onStopLoadinClick: function (button, e, options) {
if(myGrid.getStore().isLoading( )){
Ext.Ajax.abort(myGrid.getStore().proxy.activeRequest);
delete myGrid.getStore().proxy.activeRequest;
 }
```

This code aborts the last ajax request and I can't specify which ajax request to abort for example: If I made 2 ajax requests then stopped the first one it will close the last one.

My Question is how can I abort specific ajax request?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I couldn't find `Ext.Ajax.abort()` and `proxy.activeRequest` in the docu, which ExtJS version are you using?

Comment: i am using extjs-4.1.1

Comment: strange didn't found it in the docu but I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15363330/1453662